# foreach loop not displaying desired result

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

Hi guys and thank you for your time. My question is regarding.

I am trying to loop over images in my folder along with a post in the database with the end result looking like this:

> Post 1 
>  Image 1
>
> Post 2 
>  Image 2
>
> Post 3 
>  Image 3

At the moment i get this result:

> Post 1 
>  Image 1
>
> Post 1 
>  Image 2
>
> Post 1 
>  Image 1
>
> Post 2 
>  Image 1
>
> Post 2 
>  Image 2
>
> Post 2 
>  Image 3

I do not want this result.

Below is my code:

```
    $post_info = get_posts();

foreach ($post_info as $info){
   $photos = glob('design/img/*');
   foreach($photos as $photo) {
    echo " <a href='feed.php?pid=".$info['post_id']." ' > 
           <div style='background:#FFF5C3'> <br> <h2> ".$info['person_mentioned']." </h2> 
        <h3 style='color: black'>    ".$info['body']." </h3> </div> </a>";
  echo " <img src='{$photo}' width='285px' height='200px' style='border: 5px solid black'>";


    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hint, it should just be a single loop :)

Comment: don't you mean the output you're getting is?
    Post 1 
    Image 1
    
    Post 1 
    Image 2
    
    Post 1 
    Image 3
    
    Post 2 
    Image 1
    
    Post 2 
    Image 2
    
    Post 2 
    Image 3

Comment: How do you associate images with database entries?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out (minus potential language specifics since I didn't actually run to check this code).. It's basically a regular for loop instead of a foreach.

```
$post_info = get_posts();
$photos = glob('design/img/*');

if (count($post_info) === count($photos)) { // According to your requirement, the counts would be the same
    $count = count($post_info);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $info = $post_info[$i];
        $photo = $photos[$i];
        echo " <a href='feed.php?pid=".$info['post_id']." ' > <div style='background:#FFF5C3'> <br> <h2> ".$info['person_mentioned']." </h2> 
        <h3 style='color: black'>    ".$info['body']." </h3> </div> </a>";
        echo " <img src='{$photo}' width='285px' height='200px' style='border: 5px solid black'>";
    }
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Indeed.. Just felt like someone should type out the answer since it might actually help the OP :P

Comment: thank you for writing out JAnderton and Erik for the tip. I ran the code you pasted above and received an error:unexpected t-string on the for line. I am assuming it was the 'i' which should be '$i'. However, when i changed it did not display anything.

Comment: Remove the "int" keyword too please.. been coding in java for the past few hours. Also corrected my above post for $i as you said. It's probably not going inside the `if` if your output is blank. Please check echo the `count($post_info)` and `count($photos)`. If both are equal, try replacing the `===` I used with `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Getting image details from `get_posts()` and removing inner `foreach` loop may fix your problem.

*Note: replace `$info['something_like_post_image']` with your image field.*

```
$post_info = get_posts();

foreach ($post_info as $info) {
    //$photos = glob('design/img/*');
    //foreach ($photos as $photo) {
    echo " <a href='feed.php?pid=" . $info['post_id'] . " ' > 
           <div style='background:#FFF5C3'> <br> <h2> " . $info['person_mentioned'] . " </h2> 
        <h3 style='color: black'>    " . $info['body'] . " </h3> </div> </a>";
    echo " <img src='" . $info['something_like_post_image'] . "' width='285px' height='200px' style='border: 5px solid black'>";
    //}
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
/*
 * If your images have any naming convention like
 * imageFileName = "image_{POST_ID}.jpg"
 * then you can use below code (NO DATABASE ENTRY REQUIRED)
 * (ie, For post #1 image file would be "image_1.jpg";
 * and for post #2 image file would be "image_2.jpg")
 */

$post_info = get_posts();

foreach ($post_info as $info) {

    //filename = image_1.jpg or image_2.jpg or...
    $photoFileName = 'design/img/' . 'image_' . $info['post_id'] . '.jpg';

    if (file_exists($photoFileName)) {
        echo " <a href='feed.php?pid=" . $info['post_id'] . " ' > 
                           <div style='background:#FFF5C3'> <br> <h2> " . $info['person_mentioned'] . " </h2> 
                        <h3 style='color: black'>    " . $info['body'] . " </h3> </div> </a>";
        echo " <img src='" . $photoFileName . "' width='285px' height='200px' style='border: 5px solid black'>";
    }
}
```

*NOTE: You should have to keep a relation with each post against your unique image; otherwise you will not be able to get that unique image with your post, while listing.
Checkout below options to handle this situation.*

1. You can keep image name in database (for each post, you can get your image name directly from database)
2. Use a naming convention for your images (for post #1 use unique image name (say image_1, for post #2 image_2 etc)

**UPDATE - 2**

If you are looking for a cycle-through images (without any condition), use below code

```
/*
 * If you are looking for a solution that cycles each images
 * along with each post, try this one
 */

$post_info = get_posts();
$photos = glob('design/img/*');

$numPhotos = count($photos) + 1;

//assuming your post# starts with 1
$imageId = 1;
foreach ($post_info as $info) {

    //cycling
    if ($imageId % $numPhotos === 0) {
        $imageId = 1;
    }

    $photoFileName = 'design/img/' . 'image_' . $imageId++ . '.jpg';

    //no need of this checking, since you are cycling
    //if (!file_exists($photoFileName)) {
    //    $photoFileName = 'path/to/default/image.jpg';
    //}

    echo " <a href='feed.php?pid=" . $info['post_id'] . " ' > 
                               <div style='background:#FFF5C3'> <br> <h2> " . $info['person_mentioned'] . " </h2> 
                            <h3 style='color: black'>    " . $info['body'] . " </h3> </div> </a>";
    echo " <img src='" . $photoFileName . "' width='285px' height='200px' style='border: 5px solid black'>";
}
```

Comment: What what it looks like, the image information isn't available in the $post_info array. The images seem to be being read out of the directory. This solution won't work.
Reference: [php glob documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: @JAnderton - do you have any relation with post_id and image name? if so, I've a solution for you...

Comment: For most requirements, I'd say you're right. There should be a link between your post_id or in general some part of the $info object that can link to the image that the OP wants to display. Alas, the question states none. If there is a link, the OP might want to consider changing the solution approach in the first place so he can use @rajukoyilandy's solution.

Comment: Yes the images are from my directory on the file system

Comment: Thanks rajukoyilandy. Yes your solution would work if the image was stored in the database when the post is submitted. So how would i do that if i want to grab an image from my directory and insert it when a new post is made? Each new post must include a different picture each time.

Comment: @user1463075 - I wouldn't compel you to store image name in database, but you SHOULD HAVE a relation with image name and post id. Checkout my new update another solution... :)

Comment: thanks works great. the only issue is that is does not display the post if there is no image associated. how would i make another condition that says if file does not exist use this default pic and then have it continue on as normal? What i basically have is folder full of images that i tack on to each post. If there are like 1000 posts i would need to have 1000 images. All i want to do is just to recycle through those images every time a new post is made. How can i do that?

Comment: @user1463075 - If you are looking for a *cycle through images* approach, checkout my **UPDATE - 2** section. :)

Comment: So sorry. Looks like a made a mistake. it cycles through the photos but one image in the middle of the cycle does not display. Any thoughts?

Comment: So whats happening is that it cycles through but when it gets to the last image and then adds 1. It tries to display an image that isnt there. Then it begins its recycle. How can we make so that it realizes if the file does not exist, dont display the nonexistent file but begin recycle?

Comment: You are welcome... :)
But I didn't notice any such issue in my example...
My bad? (still thinking...)